# How to send data from a JTextField to a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jlist

I have integrated a form to store the data from a `JTextField` to a variable after a user enters something and presses a `JButton`. My issue is that I want to send this data to a `JList` every time they type something in and hit the submit button.

How is this possible?

Comment: *"How is this possible?"*  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) showing where you're at.

Comment: BTW - add an `ActionListener` to the text field and it will fire on the user pressing `Enter` (the button then becomes redundant).

Comment: Post some valid code what have you tried and then we will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an ActionListener to the instance of the JButton, get the content of the JTextField (say with name aTextField), and store it to a list (say you have a class member *JList dataInputted* )

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                dataInputted.addElement(aTextField.getText());
            }
        });
```

Comment: an ArrayList is not a `JList`

Comment: That answered my question. Thanks! I was getting confused on my assignment the integration of Jlist and vectors instead of arraylists, but I read through the API and got it figured out now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Modified it to use JList. My bad.

Comment: Actually i can't find `addElement` method in JList api.